# selecting rows from 2D array not in another 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

i want to choose randomly 25% rows of a 2D array the return the rows i choosed and not choosed also.

Example:

```
cols = [['republican' 'n' 'y' 'n' 'n' 'y']
 ['republican' 'n' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'n']
 ['democrat' 'y' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'n']
['republican' 'n' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'y']]

new = [['democrat' 'y' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'n']]

rem = [['republican' 'n' 'y' 'n' 'n' 'y']
 ['republican' 'n' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'n']
['republican' 'n' 'y' 'y' 'n' 'y']]
```

here is my code :

```
def splitRandom(cols, percent):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    new = cols[np.random.choice(cols.shape[0], int(cols.shape[0]*(percent/100)), replace=False)]
    rem = #help here
    return new,rem
```

i tried to use setdiff1d but didn't work and i don't know how to mask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code slightly:

```
def splitRandom(cols, percent):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    choise = np.random.choice(cols.shape[0], int(cols.shape[0] * (percent / 100)),replace=False)
    new = cols[choise]
    rem = np.delete(cols, choise, axis=0)
    return new,rem
```

edit: I assume cols is a numpy array

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach that avoids modification of the input array:

```py
def splitRandom(cols, percent):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    choise = np.random.choice(cols.shape[0], int(cols.shape[0] * (percent / 100)),replace=False)
    mask = np.zeros(cols.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    mask[choise] = True
    return cols[mask], cols[~mask]
```

Note that this sort of operation is common enough that machine learning frameworks often have built-in methods to do it efficiently; for example, here is the equivalent using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_test_split(cols, train_size=0.25)
```